# Universal UHF algebra

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras

I am reading on quasidiagonal $C^*$-algebras. There the phrase "the universal UHF algebra" appears. I know what UHF algebras are, but I don't know what the universal UHF algebra is. I would be glad about an explanation or reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the universal UHF algebra people usually mean the UHF algebra with
the associated supernatural number:
$$\prod_{p\in \mathbb{P}}p^\infty.$$
In other words, UHF algebra is the the unique UHF algebra $A$ with $K_0(A)=\mathbb{Q}$.

A good reference is Rørdam's *Classification of Nuclear C${}^\ast$-Algebras*.